# sequelize findAll empty but there is info

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, findall

I am working with two calls, one is creating a row in the table correctly.  When I then use the findAll call though (no filters or settings so should be all data in the table) it is returning an empty array but no error.

I have tried creating a new table and new model etc to try and rule them out but I get the same result.
I have also tried using root credentials to rule out restrictions on the table.
I have tried changing Payments to other tables like Users and it works as expected.

this is the call:

```
    let all_payments = [];
    [err, all_payments] = await to(Payments.findAll());
    if (err) return ReE(res, err);
    return ReS(res, "TEST", all_payments);
```

Comment: simply try `await Payments.findAll()` and have a look

Comment: @Sagar I have tried this with the User table and again it works but the Payments table just times out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the table needed to be capital Payments instead of payments, unlike the other tables.  Not sure why but will leave it that way until I do

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).